# What does this HTML code mean?

Tags: css, html

I found the following HTML code

```
<i data-toggle="tooltip" class="icon-ok-sign" data-original-title="File not detected"></i>
```

on https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/9d72e0523cc6bd4baa1bd88967aec1402551a5d565703b799ce6be52ec1a7640/analysis/

Why they are using <i>? 
How to get path for the "icon-ok-sign" icon? 
How can I find out the icon path with the Chrome browser menu item "Inspect Element"?

Comment: What does this HTML code *do* is probably more appropriate.

Comment: looks like Bootstraps tooltip : http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips

Comment: Please check this - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons

Comment: They are using `<i>` because they are one of those clueless developers who don't understand semantics and proper use of markup.  Unless of course they just want to italicize something. ;)

Comment: Its a bootstrap related tag to display icons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are using [bootstap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) as their framework.

Bootstrap includes an icon pack called glyphicons. It's a sprite file, and has these icons in: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#icons.

In this site they are using an icon font, the popular [Font Awesome.](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)

The icons are in the font, rather than as images, which has many advantages.

The reason they use the `i` tag, is because Bootstrap decides to use that to represent an icon. Personally I don't really like that – `i` = italic, but on the other hand, its a purely stylistic tag and isn't really used anyway. (`em` should be used for emphasis, not `i`).

The tooltip stuff is also from Bootstrap and the documentation is [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips).

Comment: I share your distaste for this corruption of the `i` tag, but I must disagree that `i` isn't really used.  Yes, `em` should be used for emphasis, but `i` is the semantically correct tag to use for elements that are not emphasized yet require italics, such as book titles, phrases in foreign languages, etc.

Comment: How to get path for the "icon-ok-sign" icon? Is there a reference to https://www.virustotal.com/static/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.1.0 in the html or css file?

Comment: Yeah, https://www.virustotal.com/static/css/bootstrap.css is the CSS, search for awesome and you'll find it. There is no path for the image, as it's not one. Derek – `i` is the wrong tag, but I can understand why they selected it. You can actually use the icons on any tag without modification – personally I use `span` where they use `i`.